# how to change async callback using promise in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I am a beginner and am currently making a User Management system in NodeJS, I had previously done it with MongoDB, Express. Right now im making it all again with Express, Sequelize and Postgresql to better understand some concepts.

What im stuck at is the reset page where I previously used Async.waterfall to get the email id and send email using SendGrid, but now I want to know how can I convert it using Promises..? It is a bit confusing to understand how to use them with concurrent callbacks.

Here is the previous code using the async.waterfall :

```
app.post('/forgotpassword', function(req, res, next) {
    async.waterfall([
        function(done) {
            crypto.randomBytes(20, function(err, buf) {
                var token = buf.toString('hex');
                done(err, token);
            });
        },
        //2
        function(token, done) {
            User.findOne({ 'local.email': req.body.email }, function(err, user) {
                if (!user) {
                    req.flash('forgotMessage', 'No account with that email address exists.');
                    return res.redirect('/forgotpassword');
                }

                user.local.resetPasswordToken = token;
                user.local.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000; // 1 hour

                user.save(function(err) {
                    done(err, token, user);
                });
            });
        },
        //3
        function(token, user, done) {

            var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
            var sgTransport = require('nodemailer-sendgrid-transport');

            var options = {
                auth: {
                    api_key: ''
                }
            };

            var mailer= nodemailer.createTransport(sgTransport(options));

            var mailOptions = {
                to: user.local.email,
                from: 'passwordreset@demo.com',
                subject: 'Node.js Password Reset',
                text: 'You are receiving this because you (or someone else) have requested the reset of the password for your account.\n\n' +
                'Please click on the following link, or paste this into your browser to complete the process:\n\n' +
                'http://' + req.headers.host + '/reset/' + token + '\n\n' +
                'If you did not request this, please ignore this email and your password will remain unchanged.\n'
            };
            mailer.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
                req.flash('forgotMessage', 'An e-mail has been sent to ' + user.local.email + ' with further instructions.');
                done(err, 'done');
            });
        }
    ],
    //2 out of Async
    function(err) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.redirect('/forgotpassword');
    });
});
```

Comment: You can use Promise.all([ ])

Comment: how @UditKumawat like what should my structure be ? i even get confused that if im using promise, should I even have to use done() ? can You just explain with example ? Will be a lot of help

Comment: @UditKumawat No, he cant, because function2 requires the result of function1, function3 result of function2 and so on. Promise.all execs promises simultaneously, each of the functions in the promiseArr cannot depend on another.

Comment: @styopdev ok thanks

Answer (score 2):

From async.waterfall documentation

> Runs an array of functions in series, each passing their results to
>   the next in the array. However, if any of the functions pass an error
>   to the callback, the next function is not executed and the main
>   callback is immediately called with the error.

So its exactly the same job as Promise.then do, just chain your promises.

```
    crypto.randomBytes(20)
    .then( function (buf) {
         var token = buf.toString('hex');
         return token;
    })
    .then( function(token) {
       return Model.User.findOne({where: {'email' : req.body.email}});
    })
    .then(function (user) {
         if(!user){
            //    throw no user found error             
         }

         return Model.User.create();

    })
    .catch( function(err) { 
       // error handling
       // catch no user found error and show flash message
    });
```

You have to have single `catch` in the end of promises chain, and `then` should not to be inside of another `.then` function. I can suggest to read this article - [We have a problem with promises](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html).

Comment: how should I include the nodemailer part ?! should I create it into a different function and then call that function by name into the .then chain ?!

Comment: Add new .then call before .catch and use return transport.sendMail(options) inside it

Comment: okay @styopdev but can I ask why are we separating them? is it because if we use a .then function inside a .then function it wont work. Is this why you have seperated the findOne method and creation ?

Comment: It will work, but its most common antipattern of promises. One of benefits of promise is that promise helps to avoid callback hell (pyramid of doom), using nested `.then` иs the same as if you were using callbacks.

Comment: okay @styopdev one last doubt i have is that when we       
 
return Model.User.findOne({where: {'email' : req.body.email}});

how does it become user in .then(funtion (user)). 

I was confused by it even when using the first time. Can you explain it ?!

Comment: and how should I send token again as a parameter to the next .then as it wont be used when we do .then(.. ) {return Model.User.findOne()  };

Comment: Please read article I have shared to get more information about promises,

Comment: Related to 2 comment, define global variable var token outside of promise, set it in the block you generate token and use in any .then block you want.

Comment: there is a new Problem when I try to run it it says crypto.randomBytes().then() is not a function.

Comment: You can use this wrapper https://gist.github.com/7h1b0/5154fda207e68ad1cefc to promisify that function